# Getting Sharepoint Context in SPWebApp Hosted on Azure

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, sharepoint

i have a Sharepoint (365) application (MVC) hosted on Azure.
My application works good if I debug it in localhost, but when i go to Azure, i can't retrieve in anyway the Sharepoint Context... is always null.

Why? Help me!

```html
 var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext.Current);
```